# Sudden Website Title Change and Order Email Notification not Working

Tags: wordpress

I am not sure about my what happened to my site but the site title suddenly change to

> +ADw-/title+AD4-Hacked By Mister Spy +ACYAJg Souheyel.+ADw-DIV style+AD0AIg-DISPLAY: none+ACIAPgA8-xmp+AD4

and my order email is not working properly. Anyone got same problem?

Do you think what happened to my site? Any Solution to this?

Comment: sounds like you need to restore from backup and/or determine how to close the holes in your wordpress site to keep that from happening again.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I am using the old version of wordpress then you recommend upgrading it?

Comment: I'm not a wordpress expert but yeah, that would be a start.  Also perhaps read up [on security tips](https://codeable.io/quick-wordpress-security-tips/) to help to lock your site down.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the clue is this: "Hacked By Mister Spy".

You got hacked because you are using an old version of WordPress. That's very typical; when running WordPress, keep it and all themes/plugins updated in order to stay safe and secure.

Since version 3.7, WordPress will automatically update itself with security fixes when they are released by WordPress. FYI, these security updates *are not* full updates to the latest version; they are patches, and you will still see advisories to fully update to the latest full version.

To correctly clean your site and hosting account of the hack, carefully follow https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked .

Then take a look at the recommended security measures in https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress and http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks